# Is it better to use AsyncTask (Or Timer) within single process, or using Service in separate process?

Tags: android

I just read [Android Architecture Tutorial: Developing an App with a Background Service (using IPC)](http://mindtherobot.com/blog/37/android-architecture-tutorial-developing-an-app-with-a-background-service-using-ipc/). It is basically

1. Have a service run in separate process.
2. A repeated timer event will occur in the service.
3. Within the timer event handler, it will perform networking to retrieve tweet, and inform all the listener attached to it. Listeners are attached to it through IPC.

I can see there are 2 major characteristics with this approach.

1. Tweet retrieving action run within separate process.
2. It always run, even the main activity has quit.

However, if "**It always run**" is not my requirement. I want everything to stop when I quit my main Activity.

1. Will it be better, if I use `AsyncTask` (Or `Timer`) within my main Activity, to perform tweet retrieving action? Everything will be run within single process. No more using `Service`.
2. Using AsyncTask (Or Timer), seems simpler. We no longer need to deal with IPC.
3. Or, using `Service` approach might be better? Am I missing some goodies provided by Service?

Answer (score 1):

Using service is a better approach as it will allow you to perform the polling independent from the application flow.

As it is a task where  no user interaction is required and it has to be done in the background without disturbing the main UI of application and whatever the user is doing, a service is an ideal candidate for its implementation.

It is possible to bind the service with the application in such a way that when the main application terminates, it will also turn off the service.

Comment: We will not using polling. We will be using the same mechanism as author approach (subject/observer). So, AsyncTask or Timer approach, will also able to provide us application flow independent facility.

Answer (score 1):

At first you have to know, that a service isn't a Thread. If a activity binds a Service and runs as a Deamon, but a ASynchTask is another thread.

**ASynchTask**'s are designed for doing some work which should not running on UI-Thread (for example processing some larger calculations)

**Services** are designed to run permanantly on Background. 
If you want to permanantly check for new tweets, even if your activity is stopped or paused, you should use a Service, which checks into an own thread for new data.

**TimerTask** are good old java style implementations which run on their own thread.
You can used them for processing some data, but you'll have some problems to manipulation UI. If you want to be it on propper "AndroidWay", use a Handler instead of TimerTask.

Comment: The requirement is that, when activity is stopped or paused, everything should be stopped and paused. Preserving customer's battery resource is a major concern. So, in that case, should we stick with AsyncTask (Timer)?

Comment: You can stop/resume a Service as well as your activity, but if you didn't want to run permanantly, you should have a look at ASyncTask or maybe on a TimerTask, which can repeat in intervals

Answer (score 1):

I would take the view that a `TimerTask` can be set to execute and repeat at a given interval, `Timer`s run on a separate thread so all this work would occur in the background without disturbing the UI. It would be easy for you to trigger an update within your app when the `TimerTask` completes and update the UI when you want.

When you exit the app it's a simple case of calling `cancel()` on your `Timer` and the purging all the tasks with `purge()`.

Nice and easy and you don't need to implement IPC, which can be very fiddly to get right.

**EDIT**

Using `AsyncTask` you can do pretty much exactly the same thing but you'll have to manually schedule the next run. I have used both solutions in the past and found them to work equally well so it's all down to your preference.

Comment: You may want to consider combining `TimerTask`s and `AsyncTask`s. Use the easily scheduled `TimerTask` to fire off an `AsyncTask` The only reason I suggest this is because `AsyncTask` can easily update the UI in a few places during the execution of a task. Pre-task in `onPreExecute()`, mid-task from `onProgressUpdate()` and then post task in `onPostExecute()`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I know the tutorial you are following...I've followed that tutorial myself while trying to learn IPC.  One thing you need to know is, The Android docs explicitly say,

> Note: Using AIDL is necessary only if you allow clients from different applications to access your service for IPC and want to handle multithreading in your service.

If at all possible, you should just [bind to the service.](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Binder)

Also, you must consider, do you really need a service?  Consider that the Android Twitter app doesn't even refresh tweets for you, its on an as needed basis.  Polling can be battery intensive, so you must consider if this is really necessary.

Also, will you be using these tweets from multiple activities?  If so it would be nice to not duplicate the code in multiple places. So maybe you do want a service in this case.

Other than that, I would recommend that you start simple (Async task with a timer to update it), and move to a service if you think you need it.

Comment: I suspect that document comment is slightly mistaken, in that it should also apply to services within the application but running in a different process (something that is atypical, but can be requested, and has been mentioned in the question).

Comment: So bottom line, do you really need this in another process? I spent way too long figuring out how to do this, and it turned out that it didn't really matter in my case if it was in its own process (sounds like your case too if your really)